# Сравнить две даты в golang

Tags: golang

Есть две даты типа time.Time;
Как правильно из сравнить?
В стандартном пакете не вижу такой функции и просто спец. символы "<",">" не работают

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В стандартном пакете не вижу такой функции

Плохо видите :-)

- [`func (t Time) After(u Time) bool`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.After)
- [`func (t Time) Before(u Time) bool`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Before)
- [`func (t Time) Equal(u Time) bool`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal)

Answer (score 1):

Можно вычесть одну дату из другой, и получить разницу в int64 наносекундах (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration)

```
if t1.Sub(t0) > 0 {...}
```